# The mystery of the disappearing asterisk

Tags: output

I have a weird "bug" in my table. For some reason one asterisk does not show up. I am using LuaLaTex which as I understand it uses Unicode so all these weird glyphs I've got in my table should be fine being printed directly and they all are, except that one asterisk! And the weird thing is that if I add a second asterisk, one appears. I have tried the table without `tcolorbox` and with `tabular` instead of `tabularx` and neither brings back the asterisk. I am stumped.

What it looks like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=TeX]{linux libertine} 

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{icelandic}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]%
\begin{footnotesize}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{lXX}
        Stofn    &  Tenging við [GULUR]         &   Orð af sama stofni   \\
        \hline
        *ƀlaikaz &  gamalháþýska: \textit{bleih} ‘gulleitur, fölur’ &   is. \textit{bleikur};   \\
                 &                                      &   dk. \textit{bleg} ‘fölur’; \\
                 &                                      &   en. \textit{bleak} ‘hráslagalegur’ \\
        \hline
        *ƀlēwaz  &  skylt latnesku \textit{flāvus} ‘gullingulur’;       &   is. \textit{blár}; \\
                 &  fornírska \textit{blár} ‘gulur’     &   dk. \textit{blå} ‘blár’; \\
                 &                                      &   en. \textit{blue} ‘blár’ \\
        \hline
        *falvaz  &  fornenska \textit{fealu} ‘gulbrúnn, gulur’; &   is. \textit{fölur}; \\
                 &  gamalsaxneska \textit{falu} ‘fölgulur’; &   en. \textit{fallow} ‘gulbrúnn’  \\
                 &  fornháþýska \textit{falo} ‘fölur, rauðgulur’;       &       \\
                 &  slavneska *\textit{polь} ‘gulur, hvítleitur’        &       \\
        \hline
        *ʒallan  &  talið skylt *\textit{g̑hel}-                    &   is. \textit{gall};  \\
        *ʒallōn  &  sanskrít \textit{hári} ‘fölur, gulleitur, grænleitur’; & en. \textit{gall} ‘ósvífni’  \\
                 &  avestíska \textit{zairi} ‘gulur, gulleitur’     &       \\
        \hline
        *ʒelwaz  &  fornenska \textit{ʒeolu} ‘gulur’;               &   is. \textit{gulur};  \\
                 &  skylt sanskrít \textit{gaurá}- ‘hvítleitur, gulleitur’; &   dk. \textit{gul} ‘gulur’;  \\
                 &  latína \textit{giluus} ‘fölgulur’;          &   en. \textit{yellow} ‘gulur’  \\
                 &  latína \textit{fuluus} ‘skærgulur’          &           \\
        \hline
        *ʒlōraz  &  sama og gríska \textit{khlorós} ‘grænleitur gulur’ & is. \textit{glor} ‘gulgrár hungurlitur’;  \\
                 &                                  &   en. \textit{chlorine} ‘klór(gas)’  \\
        \hline
        *ʒlūmaz  &  skylt grísku \textit{khloús} ‘grænleitur gulur’ & is. \textit{Glúmur} ‘björn’; \\
                 &                              &   en. \textit{glum} ‘dökkur, daufur, leiður’  \\
        \hline
        *xunaʒgan & tengt grísku \textit{knikós} ‘fölgulur’ &   is. \textit{hunang}; \\
                 &                                          &   en. \textit{honey} ‘hunang’  \\
        \hline
        *pađđōn  &  fornírska \textit{buide} ‘gulur’        &   is. \textit{padda}; \\
                 &                                          &   dk. \textit{padde} ‘froskur’  \\
        \hline
        *salwaz  &  fornnorræna \textit{sǫlr} ‘gulur’       &   is. \textit{söl}  \\
                 &  miðhollenska \textit{salu} ‘skítugur, fölur, gulur’ &   en. \textit{sallow} ‘gugginn, fölur’  \\
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{footnotesize}
    \caption{Germanskir stofnar íslenskra litaorða}
    \label{tafla:gulur}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I realise that since I've technically found a solution (adding the second asterisk) it wouldn't be a problem, per se, but this is really bugging me. So if anyone has any ideas why this would be happening, please tell me.

Comment: Aside from the question itself, its title is perfect for a 7+ imdb-rated thriller :)

Comment: The line-ending ``\\`` scans for the following token since ``\\*`` is a valid command. Use ``\\\relax`` on the previous line.

Comment: That's "normal". `\\` looks for a `*` and absorbs it.

Comment: If you like to live dangerously, just before the `tabularx` environment, you can add ``\makeatletter
\def\@arraycr{\relax\iffalse{\fi\ifnum 0=`}\fi\@xarraycr}
\makeatother`` to disable scanning for the `*`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik usually I would jump at the chance to live dangerously but this is my doctoral thesis so I think I'll have to err on the side of caution this time. :p (but I will put this code into my example file and save it to play with at a later date).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You hothead daredevil `:-)`

Comment: @Plergux I know what you mean :-)  I have a copy of TeX Live installed just so an update won't accidentally break mine

Comment: @Fran, Yes, thank you. I will add it to my "documentation" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{5cm}{lX}
\show\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

gives the terminal output

```
> \\=macro:
->\relax \iffalse {\fi \ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifstar \@xarraycr \@xarraycr .
```

Apart from the brace hack, there is a `\@ifstar` followed by two occurrences of the same macro `\@xarraycr`. This means that both `\\` and `\\*` have the same effect. Now, the `\@ifstar` macro is based on `\@ifnextchar`, which does a good job at *ignoring* spaces after it. The side effect in cases like this is that a `\\` followed by a new line follwed by `*` is interpreted as `\\*`. You must therefore "stop" the scanning of `\@ifnextchar` and use e.g. `\\ \relax` if your line starts with a `*`.

Comment: Thank you for this most enlightening insight into the innards of TeX :D

Comment: @Plergux That's not quite the innards of TeX but of the LaTeX kernel. Anyway, you are welcome `:-)`.